restart puppeteer browser after some limit/time to save CPU and Storage is necessary?
I am using puppeteer for scrapping URLs. Is it necessary to restart (close and then launch) puppeteer browser after some limit?

Can Restarting browser benefit processing?
Can Restarting browser can remove storage issues?


var response_ = await this.page.goto(url, { waitUntil: ['load'],
timeout: 60000 });

I tried this code.

This is too broad. What's the specific problem, exactly? No, it shouldn't be necessary to restart a browser. Can you clarify what led you to believe that it would be? The code you showed is a simple goto that does nothing out of the ordinary--I don't see how that's relevant to the question. Thanks.

Like @ggorlen said, question is too broad. Please add some details. For example, if you are having storage issues that are caused by cookies/cache/temp files and you have set proper cleanup methods on browser close, yes you should close the browser after some time to cleanup cache and other temp files that cause storage issues.
